# In R, collapse over multiple logical rows of the same ID into 1 row

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

**Problem:** To do some survey analysis on prescription drug use in `R`, I need to turn multiple rows of the same person (ID) into one, indicating `TRUE` if any of said rows has `TRUE` in it.

Here's the data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a"), 
                cardiovasc = c(T,T,T,T,T,T), 
                beta_blockers = c(F,F,F,F,F,F),
                antibiotics = c(T,F,F,F,F,F),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here's what I'd like it to look like:

```
goal <- data.frame(ID = c("a"),
                    cardiovasc = c(T), 
                    beta_blockers = c(F),
                    antibiotics = c(T),
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

As you can tell, even though `df$antibiotics` only had 1 `TRUE` in the dataset, I'd like that to count as `TRUE` when the ID has been collapsed into one row.

**What I've tried:**

Mainly, I've been trying to work off [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068734/r-collapse-multiple-rows-into-1-row-same-columns), and while I feel I'm close, I nevertheless get an error. Here's my attempt:

```
df <- df[, lapply(.SD, paste0, collapse=""), by=ID]
```

Which yields `unused argument (by = ID)`. I've tried another approach from the same post, but that's even messier and requires me to make the data a `data.table`. I need to keep things as a `data.frame`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `any` instead of `paste` as `any` will check for any TRUE elements in the column, grouped by 'ID'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, any), ID]
```

-output

```
#   ID cardiovasc beta_blockers antibiotics
#1:  a       TRUE         FALSE        TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use this `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(cardiovasc:antibiotics, ~ any(.x)))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  ID    cardiovasc beta_blockers antibiotics
  <chr> <lgl>      <lgl>         <lgl>      
1 a     TRUE       FALSE         TRUE
```

**Updated**
Thank you dear @Ray for bringing up a very likely scenario:
In case the column values were `1` & `0` instead of `TRUE` & `FALSE` and also taking into account the presence of `NA` values among them we could use the following solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(cardiovasc:antibiotics, ~ any(.x[!is.na(.x)] == 1)))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  ID    cardiovasc beta_blockers antibiotics
  <chr> <lgl>      <lgl>         <lgl>      
1 a     TRUE       FALSE         TRUE
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","a","a","a","a"), 
                 cardiovasc = c(1,1,1,1,1,1), 
                 beta_blockers = c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 antibiotics = c(1,0,0,0,0,0),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: If, in the original dataframe, the `cardiovasc`, `beta_blockers`, and `antibiotics` variables were just 1/0 instead of logical T/F, how would I get your solution to work? I'm encountering some errors I think have to do with the logical type of these indicators, and I'd like to try using your solution on 1/0 versions of these variables. I tried replacing "any" with "paste" and "paste0", but while no errors occur the resulting dataframe is unchanged.

Comment: if you want to use `any()` which checks for TRUE. `any()` also coerces a 0/1 vector into a logical vector. Thus, it should work out of the box. However, you have to take care of NAs, as any will return NA if you have missing values. If you do not trust the `any()` coercion, "recode" your 0/1 into TRUE/FALSE (this way you also have to deal with NAs) and use the given solution.

Comment: dear @logjammin, I have updated my solution for that case. Please check it now.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @Ray for bringing such likely scenario to my notice. I really appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Thanks everyone so much for their help -- it's great to have a tidyverse solution to this, and a flexible one at that.