# Collapsing rows based on grouping variable and removing empty entries

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have a data set that looks something like this

```
user_id <- c(12345,12345,12345,12345,12345,12356,12356,12356,12356,12356)
r1 <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r2 <- c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA)
r3 <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA)
r4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA)
r5 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1)

df <- data.frame(user_id,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

I would like to be able to remove the blank spaces (my data actually has NA's in these spaces, so that each user ID has only one row, with all of the ratings on the same row. I have tried using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068734/r-collapse-multiple-rows-into-1-row-same-columns) to figure things out but I would like to keep it as a data frame etc. The process from the original post hasn't been working for me so far. Ideally, I would like to stick to the tidyverse but at this point I am just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Pivoting it to long format is usually helpful here, as it allows us to work more easily with the grouping variable; in this case, removing any lines which have `""` and then pivoting to a wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-user_id) %>% 
    filter(value != "") %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from="name")
```

In the case that the values are `NA` change the `filter1` command to `filter(!value %in% NA)`,

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  user_id r1    r2    r3    r4    r5   
    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   12345 1     1     1     1     1    
2   12356 1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: This seems to have worked really well! However, my NA values have been replaced with NULL values that I can't seem to replace when using replace_with_na_all. Do you have any advice for tackling that?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure exactly what you mean - your original dataset doesn't have any `NAs`. Are the empty cells ``""`` actually ``NAs`` or NULLs in the original dataset?

Comment: The empty cells are actually NA's, I mentioned it in the post but for the sake of simplicity I left them blank in the sample data. This probably wasn't the best idea though.

Comment: @AdrienMcCulloch yeah they will behave differently. If you update your question I can update the answer.

Comment: Updated. This is made slightly more complicated by the fact that each user has a different amount of r columns. Meaning that each user potentially has between 1 and 7 raters that rated them, causing NA values when others don't have the same amount of raters.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `gather` and `spread`:

```r
user_id <- c(12345,12345,12345,12345,12345,12356,12356,12356,12356,12356)
r1 <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r2 <- c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA)
r3 <- c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA)
r4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA)
r5 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,1)

df <- data.frame(user_id,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -user_id) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  spread(key, value)
#>   user_id r1 r2 r3 r4 r5
#> 1   12345  1  1  1  1  1
#> 2   12356  1  1  1  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using base R, assuming your actual data has the same regularity:

```
df |> 
  stack() |>
  subset(values != "" & (ind != "user_id" | !duplicated(values))) |>
  unstack()


#   user_id r1 r2 r3 r4 r5
# 1   12345  1  1  1  1  1
# 2   12356  1  1  1  1  1
```